# Set constraint widgets dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, frontend, android-constraintlayout

You can easily create constraints in the layout xml:

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [bilder-upload.eu](https://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/1e283e-1570450851.png))</sub>

However I was not able to do the exact same thing in code.
May somebody help to transfer the following xml into java code?

```xml
<TextView
    ...
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/details"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I tried the following code for setting the margins, but it does not work. The textView is always at the same place.

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(textView.getLayoutParams());
layoutParams.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
description.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

Constraints are not a part of LayoutParams.

What you are looking for is **[ConstraintSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet)** set on the ConstraintLayout itself.

```
    final ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
    constraintSet.connect(R.id.textViewId, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.details, ConstraintSet.TOP,10 /*"DP"*/);
    constraintSet.connect(R.id.textViewId, ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END,10 /*"DP"*/);
    constraintSet.connect(R.id.textViewId, ConstraintSet.START, R.id.image, ConstraintSet.END,10 /*"DP"*/);
    constraintSet.connect(R.id.textViewId, ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP,10 /*"DP"*/);
    constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

Bear in mind that value you pass as the last param will be in pixel when in code so you will have to convert it to dimension pixels(DP).